# Cannot start Virtual Box 6.1.x on Windows 10 Pro build 1903?

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, services

[image: Text]
\
Unfortunately, it appears that somewhere in the flux between WSL / Hyper-V and the Virtual Machine that Windows uses to protect your credentials I can no longer run VirtualBox.

I'm very, very frustrated by this;

I've been in the bios, in bcdedit, in optionalfeatures, services.msc and I still cannot for the life of me get this thing to work!!!

**BIOS:**

To start off; in the bios, all the virtualization settings are turned on...except the one that seems like it would prevent it from working:

I made sure that the following were turned on:

[image]

[image]

Except for this one, I left it off as it seems like it might cause VirtualBox not to work:

[image]

**BOOT LOAD CONFIG**

I made a copy of the bootload configuration with
Batchfile

```
bcdedit /copy {current} /d "Windows 10 Hyper-V"
```

And this resulted in a uuid and so I changed the hypervisor setting to off:
Batchfile

```
bcdedit /set {current} hypervisorlaunchtype Off
```

And now when I load the computer I get two configuration to choose from, the one at the top has hypervisorlaunchtype set to off, but it still doesn't work.

[image]

**WSL**

I read over here that  you can't use VirtualBox and WSL at the same time, I'm not sure what to do about that, though I would like to use VirtualBox and switch back to WSL when needed even if it means a reboot.  (That said, I'd also like not to loose the files I have in WSL).

(Also I probably need to know if I'm using WSL 2 or WSL...I'm thinking it's WSL 2)

**Hyper-V**

I also tried uninstalling / installing Hyper-V via optionalfeatures.  Initially I thought maybe uninstalling it would allow me to use VirtualBox, but that is not the case.

What happens when I do try to run VirtualBox?

I get the following error message, even if I run it as administrator or with the Local Administrator Account Logged in:

[image]

**services.msc**

Also there is a VirtualBox service listed that I am unable to start:

[image]

And I get the following error after trying to start it:

[image]

**Additional interesting things:**

If I try to look up basic things like the processor and how much RAM I have installed I get nothing:

[Image](https://content.spiceworksstatic.com/service.community/p/post_images/0000397885/5ec3469f/attached_image/ProcessorNotAvailable.png)

But in services WMI is running; I don't know which of these many things the issue stems from, but I just want to run my Virtualization; it used to be so simple; you installed it and it worked!  Then Microsoft decided to make that difficult.

The only things I can see that seems to have something to do with this that I haven't played around with is the WSL issue and the Windows hidden VM that protects credentials and I don't know how to turn either of those off or disable them.

I uninstalled WSL 1 and rebooted, and now I get a different error message regardless of if I have booted using `hypervisorlaunchtype Off` or `hypervisorlaunchtype Auto`:

[image: Off or Auto same error]

And I went back to services to see that the VBoxSDS services error is still timing out (in both states), just as above:

[image: VBoxSDS]

I don't know what else I can try to fix this...apart from installing Linux.

Answer (score 4):

> Unfortunately, it appears that somewhere in the flux between WSL / Hyper-V and the Virtual Machine that Windows uses to protect your credentials I can no longer run VirtualBox.

The issue you describe has nothing to do with WSL or Hyper-V.

> I read over here that you can't use VirtualBox and WSL at the same time, I'm not sure what to do about that, though I would like to use VirtualBox and switch back to WSL when needed even if it means a reboot. (That said, I'd also like not to loose the files I have in WSL).

Windows 10 version 1903 does not support WSL 2.  **Additionally, WSL 2 does not actually create a conflict with VirtualBox, since WSL 2 does not require Hyper-V**

> I probably need to know if I'm using WSL 2 or WSL

You are running Windows 10 version 1903 which means you are only able to run WSL 1 instances.

> get the following error message, even if I run it as administrator or with the Local Administrator Account Logged in:
>
> [image]

This is caused by a VirtualBox configuration error which is extremely easy to fix.

1. Backup the contents of `%USERPROFILE%\.VirtualBox\` into another directory.
2. Delete `%USERPROFILE%\.VirtualBox\VirtualBox.xml` and the `.VirtualBox` directory itself.
3. Reboot
4. Uninstall VirtualBox
5. Reboot
6. Reinstall the current version of VirtualBox
7. Reboot
8. After the removal of the .xml file and the directory VirtualBox should run normally.  However, by removing the VirtualBox.xml, you will have to add your virtual machines again in order to turn them on.  If your previous copy of VirtualBox.xml is not 0 bytes you will be able to use it.  if your unable to use your previous copy of VirtualBox.xml you will have to import your previous virtual machines as an existing machine.

Source: [Failed to acquire the VirtualBox COM object](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=87691&start=15)

Comment: But should I use ‘hypervisorlaunchtype Off’ or ‘hypervisorlaunchtype Auto’?  I think the latter’ but I’m not sure.

Comment: My assessment above is based on this forum post: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=90853

Comment: Hyper-V is still not compatible with VirtualBox but the error you receive has nothing to do with Hyper-V or WSL.

Comment: Okay; so given that my previous comment doesn't make a difference; I've tried the steps you've given me, but they didn't fix the issue.  It is still displaying the VirtualBox COM object error when I try to start it; and I still get `Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.` when I try to start the `VirtualBox System Service`.

Comment: @leeand00 - So it actually does make a difference but you would recieve an entirely different error message due to Hyper-V.  Your error message is due to the service being unable to start.  I have to ask why are you attempting to manually start the service?  I didn't actually indicate to manual start the service at any point.

Comment: Oh; it's just one of the steps I was using to troubleshoot, since when I see the error message after starting VirtualBox, it mentions a `SERVICE_REQUEST_TIMEOUT` and that's the only service I have in my services that mentions `V*Box*` and `Used as a COM server for virtualization API`